# How to get value of a element whose name is string1.string2

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, struts1

In My web app I am using `Struts 1.x`, In one of my Jsp I need to validate some fields, I have used `Struts 1.x` html tags, for some reason I need to use nameing convention as below.

```
 <html:form action="someAction">
    <html:text property="Object.textId"    />
   </html:form>
```

What my problem here is when I want to validate that Text field in my JAva Script I am using 
below Methodology

```
function validate()
{
    var frm = eval("MyFormName");//The form name which I havve mentioned in Struts-config.xml
   var ss =  frm.Object.textId.value;// Here I cant get the value of my texte field it says it cant find  textid
   // error seems to be resonable so I have given below try but still it didnt work

 var ss= frm.+'Object.textId'.value;

 }
```

I need javascript to recognise my naming of my fields which contains dot `.` in it.

I can not change  my fiekds names to some notation.

thanks In advance.

**Edit**

I need to pass my form fields names to some other validation fuctions, In these functions they are trying to get the value as below

```
var sss=eval(document.+'FormName'+.+'FieldName');
```

Thanks In advance.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/2yrvhyaf/ like this

Comment: If it is struts1, why did you tag it struts2 ? :)

Comment: @Tushar I can get Value Like this but the problem here is I will pass my field name to another validation methods which are not in my control, those methods just need name of the fields in the form

Comment: @AndreaLigios dont know I just tagged as Struts1 only but some it has taken Struts2 :)

Comment: `eval`?! Why? Why not just use normal JS DOM functions?

Comment: Its legacy code I cant change that now...